# Android error while building after adding admob dependency 17.1.1

Tags: android, admob

In my project minimum `api` is 21 and `target api` is 28. Now, after compiling the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1` I got following error,

> C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Eckhart_Tolle_Quotes\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41\android\support\loader**

I am using android studio 3.2. I searched many questions but couldnt find the answer.please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

Add end of your build.gradle(Module:APP)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
google()
jcenter()
}
```

Comment: api 26.1.0 with 16.0.0 worked , //Add end of your build.gradle(Module:APP)//  i will try this later. thankyou

Comment: @Anvin Whenever you find a answer helpful, please accept it as the answer!